Density of random amount of time spent by a continuous time markov chain, in state 0
Consider a continuous time Markov chain, with diagram rate as shown. Suppose that the chain starts in state 0. Let $X_0(t)$ be the amount of time the chain spends in
state 0 between times 0 and t. Let T be an exponentially distributed random variable with mean $\lambda$, independent of ${X(t)}$. Calculate the probability density function of $X_0(T)$.

I have an idea to rely on the construction of the continuous time markov chains, I would to find the conditional distribution of X_o(T) given T=t, but I don't know how to find the number of jumps, how to proceed ? Anyone has references ?

The key idea to this problem is to think about "races" between the transition time $\mathrm{Exponential}(1)$ and the stop time $T \sim \mathrm{Exponential}(\lambda)$. Thanks to the memoryless property, whenever a transition happens, we can "restart the $T$ clock" and consider a new race. A standard result about such exponential races is that the race length is $\mathrm{Exponential}(1 + \lambda)$, the $\mathrm{Exponential}(\lambda)$ wins the race with probability $\frac{\lambda}{1 + \lambda}$, and the race winner is independent of the race length.
Here's what this looks like for the problem at hand. We start in state $0$. We run a race to find out if we stop or transition. With probability $\frac{\lambda}{1 + \lambda}$, the stop time wins the race. With probability $\frac{1}{1 + \lambda}$, we transition to state $1$, and we start a new race. With probability $\frac{\lambda}{1 + \lambda}$, we stop. And with probability $\frac{1}{1 + \lambda}$, we go back to state $0$, and we start a new race. And so on.
So, how long do we spend in state $0$? Each race that happens in state $0$ takes $\mathrm{Exponential}(1 + \lambda)$ time, with each race length i.i.d. When a race in state $0$ ends, there's a $\bigl(\frac{1}{1 + \lambda}\bigr)^2$ chance that we make it back to state $0$ for another race. This means the number of races that happen in state $0$ is $\mathrm{Geometric}\bigl(1 - \bigl(\frac{1}{1 + \lambda}\bigr)^2\bigr)$, and this is independent from the lengths of the races.
So the question boils down to: what is the sum of geometrically many exponentially distributed random variables? A standard result (which you can prove using e.g. generating functions) says that summing $\mathrm{Geometric}(p)$ many i.i.d. $\mathrm{Exponential}(\mu)$ random variables has distribution $\mathrm{Exponential}(p \mu)$. This means $$X_0(T) \sim \mathrm{Exponential}\biggl(1 + \lambda - \frac{1}{1 + \lambda}\biggr).$$
Remark 1. Both of the standard results, i.e. the one about exponential races and the one about summing geometrically many exponentials, are equivalent to standard facts about splitting and merging Poisson processes. I find the Poisson process facts easier to remember, and they also give some intuitive insight. But you don't need the Poisson process perspective to solve the problem.
Remark 2. The same rough idea would work for any Markov chain. Assuming you start in state $0$, you always have $X_0(T) \sim \mathrm{Exponential}(p_\lambda (\lambda + \mu))$, where $\mu$ is sum of transition rates out of $0$, and $p_\lambda$ is the probability that any given "exponential race" in state $0$ is the last.

Would you mind continuing on to find the pdf? While yours is an insightful observation, it doesn’t make the solution apparent to me. I also want to note that you might’ve meant $X_T = T$ above.

Whoops, I realize I misunderstood the notation. Will edit my answer sometime later today, which should clarify things.

Okay, answer now fixed!

Fantastic answer. One clarifying point, when you say "the number of races is $\text{Geometric}\left( 1 - \left( \frac{1}{1 + \lambda} \right)^2 \right)$ ..." do you mean "the number of races in state $0$ ..."?

Yes, the geometric only counts races in state $0$—now fixed.
